Average filter of a signal in C
I'm having troubles designing a code for an ADC measurement, I'm trying to read a signal that comes from charging a battery with pulses, so the signal will be something like the photo uploaded. Obviously I can't read one only value, because it can be in any part of the signal. So I want an average filtered value of my signal (it has a frequency of 50 Hz). The pic used is pic16f18076, which has computation modes with the ADC. I tried to do it without the computation mode, but is not accurate, maybe because I still don't understand how much values should I take, and when should I make the average. Thanks!
PD: RMS value is meaningless here, because the signal is always positive.



What's the actual mathematical relationship between the values in the signal and the "wanted measurement"? 2. What's your sampling rate?


RMS value of a unipolar signal is not 'meaningless' and it's different from average in general (for DC it will be the same). You probably actually do want average  in this case.

Average is easy (sum and divide by N), but may not be what you want since you'd be averaging in values artificially boosted by the charger and so get too high a value. Can you record when the charger pulses and exclude those values? Or gate your measurements some other way? Lots of ways you could make an ADC record at the right time.

@ThePhoton  "wanted measurement" is what I described, an average value of the signal. The signal frequency is 50Hz, and the pic that is used, has a 32 Mhz Clock. So it can be up to 640.000 samples per cycle.

@user1850479 I can't, maybe if I had a zero cross detector, but It's already being used for something else... I have no problem reading the values boosted by the transformer that's charging the battery. But I'm new at "filtering signals" and I not understand how much samples should be taken.

A low-pass filter will have a time constant so there will be some lag and some ripple. That's a design trade-off. You could also make a boxcar average but that has issues with where the edge fall. If you look at your diagram the purple line can't get to where it is until the filter sees a bunch of pulses in real time or it would violate causality. An IIR low pass filter might do what you want. Maybe.

@SpehroPefhany Yes, I searched a little, and understand what's the difference. As you say, I want an average value...

@SpehroPefhany Actually, I can wait the initial time, until the filter can have better results. I can accept 2% of ripple approximately, and filtered values each 2 or 3 seconds its Ok!

@samuelmattio, "an average" is not very specific. Do you want the (arithmatic) mean value? Do you want the median? Do you want the geometric mean?  Wikipedia has a list of nearly 2 dozen kinds of "average" here.

@ThePhoton I even don't know that, I think it will be a Mean average. The easiest way that I can tell you what I want is that the value wanted is the same as if I connect a voltmeter in DC mode.

Its important to synchronize the measurements. If you have a OS or a schedule, that would be great as you can schedule the measurements for half of your time period.

Here is a simulation of a low-pass filter with about a 300ms time constant. After a few seconds it has fairly well settled with about 1.2% ripple.
If you download LTspice or use some other similar program you can play with the values. Only R1 and C1 matter (the product of their values, to be specific) the stuff on the left is just to generate a worst-case signal similar to yours.

This could be implemented digitally as an IIR filter or as an analog filter ahead of the ADC. I have not looked at what the module on the PIC can do by itself, but digitally an IIR filter is about as easy as π.
You sample periodically at fs and add \$\alpha\$ times the reading to (1-\$\alpha\$) the accumulated value where \$\alpha = 1-e^{-1/\tau}\$, so for sampling at 1kHz and a 300ms time constant- \$\tau\$ is 300 samples so you'd use about 0.003. The PIC may not be able to do floating point multiplications in sufficient precision (you need more bits than the final result, as should be obvious) that fast and still have time to do other stuff, so straightforward C might not work for you. But there are tricks like using shifts and integer/fixed point math.
This is just a 'dumb' way to do it, there are more sophisticated ways of filtering, especially since you know the fundamental frequency of what you're trying to filter out, but if this will work for your application- it's simple and you can get on with things.

I tried to make low-pass filter, but I had no idea what cutoff frequency should I use, how did you calculate these values? Thanks for the program, will be trying it! Also, a 300K resistor, does not interfere with the ADC internal circuit of pic?

I didn't really calculate it, just picked something that I thought would be about right.

You wouldn't use a 300kΩ resistor directly with the PIC. If your source impedance is low you could use a lower resistor and a larger capacitor (probably the best choice), or you could add a buffer CMOS op-amp.

If I'm taking 200 samples per cycle, I will be sampling at 10000hz. My cutoff frequency will be 10khz/2=5000Hz. uC datasheet says that the maximum impedance recommended is 1khz. So a 10uF capacitor, with 1Kohm resistor, at 10000hz sample frequency. Will be around 1Khz of impedance, I'm correct?

You need to oversample the ADC so that it is more than 10 times the frequency of the analog signal being measured for best results. Looking at the datasheet of Pic16f18076,it has several ADC clock frequencies ranging from 1 MHz to 32 Mhz which is ample for your application. Choose a ADC clock of 500 Khz or 1 Mhz much above 5000 Hz. Try to detect when there is a rising edge of the input signal, set a flag and do ADC conversions manually when you see the flag set. Clear the flag when you detect a zero in input voltage. You can do it with a ISR so that you will always measure some positive value.You can do a calculation of how many analog to digital conversions can be measured in a time period of 0.125 seconds with the signal having a on time of 50% considering the ADC clock frequency, mux's settling time etc.If there is a always on hardware based converions in the ADC, try to see if it fits the use case. You can implement different types of filters like below:

Measure ten highest values of ADC voltage in one time period and take their average.
Measure the highest value in one time period of the signal, take its average.

There may be other types of filters but these might suffice.If you want higher resolution of ADC measurements, you can also choose 20 or 100 ADC measurements and take their average. Taking more samples would mean more code as the data structure to implement the filter would be bigger.

Pic16f18076 has 24kb of memory, so I think that I could use a lot of samples. Will it be better if I use 32Mhz ADC? Or should I use 1Mhz? My signal never cross zero, because it has the DC component of the battery. In case that I take several samples, should be important when I start to take these samples?

32 Mhz ADC clock might be an over kill. You can try with 1 Mhz ADC clock and if its not sufficient, choose higher ADC clock.  Since the rising edge and falling edges are not sharp in the signal .You can use a level detection interrupt so that an interrupt is triggered when the MCU sees a positive value beyond certain limit.

And what about the last thing I said? It will be relevant when I start doing measures if I take, for example, 100 samples?

You might do 100 measurements in one time period if that helps. There is certainly a benefit if you have more samples for your filter.

Yes, but my doubt is when starting to measure the signal, if I start in the middle of a peak, will it be problematic?

This is why you need to create a interrupt at the rising edge and at the falling edge. SInce the rising and falling edges of the pulses are not sharp, you can use a level change interrupt for rising and falling edges. This would measure the ADC value when the signal is 1/3 or 1/2 of 3.3V or 5V. The disadvantage of this is that you may not be able to calculate the average value of the signal shown by the line easily. You can estimate at what level the level interrupt is triggered and perhaps with that you can estimate average value of ADC conversion.

You can run it through an low pass filter for the average value you seek.
If you do not want the DC-offset you run the signal through a high-pass filter (<10 Hz) first to remove the DC offset.
I do not know of the numeric ranges and capabilities of PIC16, but you can probably do this with a few exponential moving average filters, those are computationally very light, but may not be very accurate.
A low pass exponential moving average filter can be implemented using this line:
y[i]=a*x[i]+(1−a)*y[i−1]
You only need the current sample (x) and previous output (y).
Coefficient a is between 0 and 1.
If you do not have an FPU I recommend converting to Qnumbers first.
You can cascade these filters for more effect.
To turn this line into a high-pass filter simply subtract y from x again.
If this signal is 50 Hz I recommend at least a 1 kHz sample rate

My code skills are pretty basic, so this will give me some troubles understanding how to code it. Qnumbers are a new world, I've never heard of them, but I think this way, is the more accurate, also not being too overkill. Thanks for all the info. Will be trying it

@samuelmattio you can get a library to help you with qnumbers, eg https://github.com/PetteriAimonen/libfixmath

Take advantage of knowing that 50 Hz pulses need averaging.

Over-sample the input wave, ensuring that peaks lie within ADC range.
Add successive samples to an accumulator for exactly 0.02 seconds.
Divide the accumulated sum by number of samples collected.

The result should be a simple average, updated every 20 milliseconds. Very easy to calculate.
Sample rate should be set by the 32 MHz clock - if it is crystal-controlled, then it should be possible to come close to an integer-number of samples in a 20ms period.

Yes, that was what I initially think... My doubts are about when starting the conversion, because I can start in the middle of a peak, will this give me problems? Or can I start measuring on any part of the signal

Oversampling any 20ms continuous segment should give you the same average result, regardless of starting point. The assumption is this: all the noise you wish to reject is 50 Hz and/or its harmonics.

A window function is easier and gives less error if the signal isn't an exact harmonic of the samplerate.
